# iOS 6 broke gmail email account (not imap type) - Send is extremely slow (5-10 minutes)

Tags: iphone, email, gmail, ios

A lot of people, myself included, cannot use their gmail account with the iPhone anymore because of an annoying iOS 6 bug. It will not send anything no matter what you do. If you switch to IMAP type then it works, but IMAP type is much worse than the gmail type which has flags, keeps sent messages synchronized and other nice things.

Does anyone manage to somehow fix that? Here are a couple of links to the problem:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4367006?start=0&tstart=0

http://www.iphoneforums.net/forum/ios-6-101/gmail-account-not-working-io6-upgrade-47163/

Comment: Same issue here too, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Two potential solutions are described in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4367006

- Replace standard SMTP server (`smtp.gmail.com`) with `smtp.googlemail.com` (using the same credentials/login details)
- Reinstall iOS 6

Comment: Can you post in the actual reply?